# How to pass email preview link to Cypress test file?

Tags: testing, next.js, cypress

I build registration form in Nextjs. When user press submit I update database and send confirmation email. **How can I pass email preview url to register.cy.ts file?**

Full implementation: I'm writing end to end test that would register user, visit [etheral-email](https://ethereal.email/message/ZW4Mg2pBbBUD-pjOZW4MvI1irCABtehCAAAABObQQcmmFmeDE13IeGZWmvU). Check if link exists. Click on the link wait for email to be confirmed, and login user.

Route.ts register

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  const testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

await nodemailer
        .createTransport({
          host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
          port: 587,
          secure: false,
          auth: {
            user: testAccount.user,
            pass: testAccount.pass,
          },
        })
        .sendMail(emailText)
        .then((info) => {
          console.log("PreviewUrl", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
        }
}
```

Register.cy.ts

```
it("displays success message", () => {
    cy.visit("en/register");

    cy.registerUI(
      "MrUniqueUser",
      "MrUniqueUser",
      emailsToDelete[0],
      "vbC1UbVWs7Y7VXoBdTrA"
    );

   // Visit nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info)
});
```